# Websphere 7: Getting 'Internal Server Error' when accessing JSPs. Servlets ok

Tags: websphere, jsp, was7

I have just installed WS 7 on our stage server. The test server was done some months ago. I have deployed the same applications to stage as on test.

One application is causing me problems. I call the login servlet but the result is an 'Internal Server Error' message. From my logs I can see that the servlet processed the log in successfully and redirects to a JSP. That is the last message. I can find no further info in any of the other standard out/err logs.

I have tried creating a simple JSP containing only HTML - same error. If I rename the file to test.html, it displays correctly. The plugin configuration appears to be identical with the one on the test server (where everything works)

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is now solved.

The installation process created a default server. I had ignored this thinking that it doesn't matter. I removed the server and regenerated the plug-in config and my app works fine.